# how to find points that are within a mile of multiple other points?

Tags: mysql, spatial-query

I have 2 MySQL tables, one containing restaurants and one containing delivery drivers. I am wanting to make a query to select a group of restaurants and also select all delivery drivers who are within a one mile radius of those restaurants. Both sets are set up as POINTs already so I think I'm looking for a geospatial query but there are that man functions that I don't really understand the differences between, and having had a look through StackOverflow I can't see any questions asking a similar thing to this. Any advice on where to start would be much appreciated, thanks!

I've just had a look through the ST_ documentation but don't really understand the difference between the functions.